# firebase middleware function for a static page (hosting)

Tags: firebase, middleware, firebase-hosting

I would like to hook up to static page requests on the firebase and to make a server side log of page loads to the firestore database. Is there any way to do it in a static hosting configuration? To make a generic handler (middleware) before serving a static page back to client?

I was trying different approaches, the only that works for me is placing the whole static folder in the functions directory from where it can be sent in response by the sendFile function (now this is not a hosting but functions service).

Works, but this is just a workaround not a good solution.

Thanks,

Comment: I'd encourage you to file a feature request for this [with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). It helps us prioritize new features (and request logging is something we're investigating).

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Hosting currently doesn't support any sort of logging of static asset requests.